# Saving an image and multiple canvas objects into a new image, with the canvas object being in an itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I recently asked about drawing items on a canvas and was shown a solution here:
[Drawing multiple items on wpf canvas results in each subsequent item being drawn below the previous even if using the same position values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76628153/drawing-multiple-items-on-wpf-canvas-results-in-each-subsequent-item-being-drawn/76628173#76628173)

However I'm now wanting to save the original image with the canvas overlays. I tried passing in the canvas to the save function but it can't find the element when running it in Rider, Visual Studio seems ok with it but the canvas appears to be blank, I'm thinking because the dots added to the canvas are paths and considered seperate maybe?

Code I've tried using:

```
XAML:
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ClickedPositions}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="SelectionOverlayCanvas"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Fill="Red">
                <Path.Data>
                    <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="2.5", RadiusY="2.5"/>
                </Path.Data>  
            </Path>  
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

<Button Content="Save and close" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=SelectionOverlayCanvas}"/>

Viewmodel:
public void SaveImageOverlay(Canvas canvas)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)canvas.ActualWidth,
        (int)canvas.ActualHeight,
        96,
        96,
        PixelFormats.Default);
    renderTargetBitmap.Render(canvas);
        
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                
    _folderPath = FolderLocations.GetRunFolder(DateTime.UtcNow);
                
    string filePath = Path.Combine(_folderPath + ".overlay.png");

    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(ImageToSave));
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);

    File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, memoryStream.ToArray());
    memoryStream.Close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See [BitmapEncoder.Frames Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.frames?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks): *Only Tagged Image File Format (TIFF), Graphics Interchange Format (GIF), and Microsoft Windows Media Photo images support more than one frame. Attempts to add additional frames to formats that do not support them will result in only the first frame being encoded.*

Comment: The MemoryStream is also pointless. The encoder could save directly to a FileStream.

Comment: Why the canvas rather than it's parent, the  itemscontrol? Which you could easily get a reference to. And why is this UI code in a viewmodel? I don't think the UI control manipulation should be in a viewmodel. Saving the result to say a database should  be but I think all or almost all that code should be in a click handler in code behind.

Comment: Ok cheers I'll have a look at other options then and look to remove the memory stream, had just gone off what I'd seen elsewhere.